# How to add features to scikit-learn DictVectorizer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, spam-prevention, naivebayes

I'm training a spam detector using the MultinomialNB model in scikit-learn. I use the DictVectorizer class to transform tokens to word counts (i.e. features). I would like to be able to train the model over time using new data as it arrives (in this case in the form of chat messages incoming to our app server). For this, it looks like the partial_fit function will be useful.

However what I can't seem to figure out is how to enlarge the size of the DictVectorizer after it has been initially "trained". If new features/words arrive that have never been seen, they are simply ignored. What I would like to do is pickle the current version of the model and the DictVectorizer and update them each time we do a new training session. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer), they use a dictionary to do the learning phase of the DictVectorizer. You could probably add your new feature to the original dictionary and do a `fit_transform`.
That way you would add your value to the DictVectoriser.

Be careful with the partial_fit method which is a kind of [heavy treatment](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.partial_fit). As it is told on the method documentation, there is treatment overhead.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
v = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
D = [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, {'foo': 3, 'baz': 1}]
X = v.fit_transform(D)

# Learn and do treatment

# when new data come (value is a dictionary)
D.append(values)
X = v.fit_transform(D) # do the fit again

# 2 choices, 
# wait for more modification before learning 
# or learn each time you have modification (not really performant)
```

Comment: This is not useful for the case of streaming very large amounts of data if I need to save the entire dictionary for all time. Then essentially, I am re-training the entire history each time new data arrives.